# posting to MongoDB returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am having troubles posting data to my mongo database. It works perfectly fine for the StudentTable, but not for the CourseTable, even though the code appears identical. I have noticed that `data` is returned with empty arrays, as you can see in the picture attached at the bottom (Console Output)

I have searched long and hard but I cannot find any question to help me.

`app.js`

```
o.create = function (student) {
    console.log("Studenttest");
    console.log(student);
    return $http.post('/students', student)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            o.students.push(data);
        });
};

o.create = function (course) {
    console.log("Coursetest");
    console.log("course");
    console.log(course);
    return $http.post('/courses', course)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log("data");
            console.log(data);
            o.courses.push(data);
        });
};
```

Console output
[image]

Edit:
As asked for, here are my models

Students.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sID: { type: Number, min: 400000, max: 500000 },
  csCourses: [String],
  Courses: [String]
  });


mongoose.model('StudentTable', StudentSchema);
```

Courses.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  courseID: [String],
  courseTimes: [String]
  });


mongoose.model('CourseTable', CourseSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post your `/courses` handler?

Comment: I think you `Schema` is defined wrongly. You App expects `courseTimes` (lowercase) and you post `CourseTimes` (uppercase). Same for `courseID`

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with MongoDB as you are showing us your http requests to a server that we know nothing for. What do you expect? :)

Comment: Valijon you were completely correct! Thank you so much I have been stuck on that for ages!

Comment: Andrey, Im sorry about the lack of clarity, I am new to programming as a whole and have a very basic understanding of everything, including how to properly show my question haha. Thanks!